# Convert column names to something from values in the 1st index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe format that looks like this:

```
       0     1     2
rev  rev1  rev2  rev3
num  num1  num2  num3
```

I want to change the column names from `0 1 2` to what is there in the 1st index and drop that index and rename the index to 0.  The desired output is

```
    rev1  rev2  rev3
0   num1  num2  rev4
```

My code does it like this

```
df.columns = df.loc['rev',:]            
df = df.drop('rev')
df.index = ['0']
```

I get the output

```
rev rev1  rev2  rev3
0   num1  num2  rev4
```

The problem with my code is that the index can be named anything and not `rev` always. If it is named anything else my code doesn't work. Also I don't want the index name to appear in the top left corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.iloc` with `df rename` by converting first row to dict i.e

```
df = df.rename(columns = df.iloc[0].to_dict()).iloc[1:]
```

Output :

```
     rev1  rev2  rev3
num  num1  num2  num3
```

If you wanto reset index then  `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: The index name doesn't reset and stays at `num`

Comment: Did u use the last line of.the answer? Use reset index

Answer (score 3):

You need `columns.name` set to `None` or another value:

```
df.columns = df.loc['rev',:]            
df = df.drop('rev')
df.index = [0]
df.columns.name = None
```

---

```
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Or use `DataFrame` constructor only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([df.loc['num'].values], columns=df.loc['rev'].values)
print (df)
   rev1  rev2  rev3
0  num1  num2  num3
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.loc['num'].values.reshape(-1, len(df.columns)), 
                  columns=df.loc['rev'].values)
print (df)
   rev1  rev2  rev3
0  num1  num2  num3
```

Comment: Ohh you took my second option. Was about to add that

Answer (score 3):

by using `T`

```
df.T.set_index('rev').T
Out[521]: 
rev  rev1  rev2  rev3
num  num1  num2  num3
```

Or

```
df.reset_index(drop=True).T.set_index(0).T.rename_axis(None,axis=1)
Out[527]: 
   rev1  rev2  rev3
1  num1  num2  num3
```

Comment: @Bharathshetty I usually do not like to modify column ~ LOL

Comment: On the long run this might be slow. Though I like it